# Modify the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array of arbitrary dimensions

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a two dimensional array.

`test_array = ones(2,2)`

I can modify the last dimension of `test_array` by doing

`test_array[:,1] = -99`.

If I had `test_array = ones(2,2,2)`,

I can do `test_array[:,:,1] = - 99`.

Suppose I want to write a function where I want to modify an array of arbitrary dimensions. For example, I could have `test_array = ones([2 for i in 1:n]...)` where `n` is arbitrary (e.g. an input for a function), and I want to modify the last dimension of `test_array`, how should I do it? Essentially I want to be able to put in an arbitrary number of `:`s when I do something analogous to `test_array[:,:,1] = -99`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do e.g.:

```
julia> n = 4
4

julia> test_array = ones([2 for i in 1:n]...)
2×2×2×2 Array{Float64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> test_array[fill(:, n-1)..., 1] .= -99
2×2×2 view(::Array{Float64, 4}, :, :, :, 1) with eltype Float64:
[:, :, 1] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

[:, :, 2] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

julia> test_array
2×2×2×2 Array{Float64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

or e.g.

```
julia> test_array = ones([2 for i in 1:n]...)
2×2×2×2 Array{Float64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> first(eachslice(test_array, dims=n)) .= -99
2×2×2 view(::Array{Float64, 4}, :, :, :, 1) with eltype Float64:
[:, :, 1] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

[:, :, 2] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

julia> test_array
2×2×2×2 Array{Float64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 -99.0  -99.0
 -99.0  -99.0

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

Comment: `fill(:, n-1)` in your solution is so cool.

Comment: It allocates though (which usually is not a problem. A non allocating version, but longer, and less standard is `ntuple(Returns(:), n-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

[EllipsisNotation.jl](https://github.com/SciML/EllipsisNotation.jl) was written for this:

```
test_array[.., 1] .= -99
```

Comment: Needs to be `test_array[.., 1] .= -99` surely. The original question has  `test_array[:,1] = -99` which also needs `.=`, else it's an error.